# Why is the crossing number of Tutte 12-cage 170?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-drawing

From the Wikipedia entry on [Tutte 12-cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tutte_12-cage#cite_note-5) , it is stated that the crossing number of Tutte 12-cage is 170, but the cited references do not seem to provide sufficient explanation for this.

[image]

- Exoo, G. "Rectilinear Drawings of Famous Graphs".
- Pegg, E. T. and Exoo, G. "Crossing Number Graphs." Mathematica J. 11, 2009.

At least, Exoo, G. only mentioned that the graph has a straight-line crossing drawing with 170 crossings, but they did not claim that its crossing number is 170.

[image]

I would like to know which specific literature explicitly states that the crossing number of this graph is 170. Otherwise, this entry is very imprecise.

Comment: I'd guess that this is just another case where Wikipedia misinterprets its sources. You could try verifying the number yourself using the [Crossing Number Web Compute](http://crossings.uos.de/), though the Tutte 12-cage may be a bit too big.

Comment: Thanks. 170 may be wrong as I see that an embedding with rectilinear crossing number 166 was found by G. Exoo (pers. comm., May 12, 2019) which QuickCross was able to reduce to a graph crossing number of 165 (E. Weisstein, May 12, 2019).  in this link https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tutte12-Cage.html

Comment: Crossing Number Web Compute seems to only support graphs with up to 100 vertices.

Comment: I've updated Wikipedia.