# Can a 3-regular non-1-planar graph be constructed?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-drawing

A $1$-planar graph is a graph which has a drawing on the plane such that each edge has at most one crossing.

I used `nauty` to generate all 3-regular graphs up to order 12, and checked each one of them individually. They all turned out to be 1-planar graphs.

My question is **whether it is possible to construct a 3-regular non-1-planar graph.**

I believe that it definitely exists.

I also conducted experiments on graphs with relatively large crossing numbers, but unfortunately, they were all 1-planar graphs. For example: The smallest 6-crossing cubic graph is the **Desargues graph**, with 20 vertices.

[image: ![![Desargues graph]

Or see  [this link](https://11011110.github.io/blog/2014/05/11/cubic-1-planarity.html)  for the hexagonal graph.

[image]

This problem is related to the question [Why is the crossing number of Tutte 12-cage 170?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441307/why-is-the-crossing-number-of-tutte-12-cage-170?_gl=1*13f7bog*_ga*NDM4NTY4MDk5LjE2MjgyNDExMTc.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3NzA1MDYzMS4xMTcuMS4xNjc3MDUwNjMzLjAuMC4w), because we know that the crossing number of an $n$-order 1-planar graph is less than or equal to $n-2$ (see [1]).

- [1] Czap J, Hudák D. On drawings and decompositions of 1-planar graphs[J]. the electronic journal of combinatorics, 2013: P54-P54.

If the crossing number of Tutte 12-cage (126 vertices)is greater than or equal to $125$, then it is the 3-regular non- 1-planar graph we are looking for. Unfortunately, it seems that the crossing number of Tutte 12-cage is unknown. It would still be helpful if we knew a good lower bound of Tutte 12-cage.

---

**Edit 1：** As reminded by Joseph O'Rourke, Coxeter graph is a candidate. The following embedding is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_graph) and it **almost has a 1-planar embedding**, **except for one edge that will cross twice.**

[image]

**Edit 2:** Thanks to Sam Hopkins for the reminder, the above sentence in Edit 1 should be corrected to:  3 of the edges will cross twice (not just one edge).

Comment: https://11011110.github.io/blog/2014/05/11/cubic-1-planarity.html isn't an answer, but suggests some candidates.

Comment: That's amazing! The problem I think about has already been studied by someone else 10 years ago.

Comment: Is a long cycle plus main diagonals 1-planar?

Comment: @Fedor, it is: if you have $2k$ vertices, arrange them in two rows, $1$ to $k$ on top and $k+1$ to $2k$ on bottom. The main diagonals are vertical edges connecting the rows. The cycle edges are horizontal, except the two edges $(1,2k)$ and $(k,k+1)$ which can be drawn around, with one crossing.

Comment: (In fact the cycle and diagonals is the Möbius ladder, I had a vague recollection but did not remember the name at first.)

Comment: Mathworld’s middle two images of the Desargues graph are 6-crossings with more symmetry, and maybe varying one of them can give a 1-planar 6-crossing too: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DesarguesGraph.html

Comment: A small complaint: $1$-planarity can be explained in a sentence or two and is not a well-known notion outside the graph-theory community. I would have liked to have this definition (I looked it up in Wikipedia and I am probably not alone). Questions should be as self-contained as possible.
(I am of course not asking for all definitions in very technical domains but it is nice to have questions understandable with almost no background).

Comment: That last diagram – I don't see any edge with more than one crossing – is something missing?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, each point on the outside connects to its polar opposite, and one of those three connections  must cross the other two.

Comment: @MattF. but in fact mustn’t all three of the connections cross the other two? So really there are three edges with > 1 crossing in this picture? Maybe I’m missing something obvious…

Comment: @SamHopkins, you are correct

Comment: @SamHopkins Are you saying that you have found a 1-planar drawing of Coxeter graph? Did I misunderstand?

Comment: @lcz: You did misunderstand me. I merely pointed out that your description "The following embedding is from Wikipedia and it almost has a 1-planar embedding, except for one edge that will cross twice." of that drawing of the graph seems wrong to me: it looks like 3 of the edges will cross twice, not just one edge.

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Can you color your version of the Desargues graph so each color is a loop of ten vertices? That would allow an easy verification of its being the Desargues graph, which would be difficult now.

Comment: @MattF.  I am sorry. Is this another separate qustion?

Comment: I understand your concern. I drew this graph myself using yEd, and it may not be easy to see if it's a Desargues graph, Please check the updated post.

Comment: @MattF. See the new editor's post

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things, but it clarifies that neither of the first two graphs pictured here is the Desargues graph, since they have no loops of length 5, while every edge in the Desargues graph is in a loop of length 5.

Comment: oh, I will check.

Comment: Does the claim that every edge in the Desargues graph is in a loop of length 5 came from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desargues_graph? Is the Desargues graph  we are discussing the same?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For each $t$, there are $3$-regular graphs that are not $t$-planar. In fact, a random $3$-regular $n$-vertex graph, for large $n$, has this property. As we'll in the proof, one can take $n=Ct(\log t)^6$ for a suitable absolute constant $C$.

Indeed, let $G$ be such a graph and suppose that it admits a $t$-planar drawing. Pick a drawing in which no three edges intersect at the same point. By adding a vertex at the intersection points, we obtain a planar graph $G'$ with at most $3tn$ vertices and at most $3tn$ edges. Maximum degree of $G'$ is at most $4$. By the Ungar--Lipton--Tarjan separator theorem, there is a set $S_1$ of $O(\sqrt{tn})$ vertices whose removal splits $G'$ into two disconnected vertex sets $V_1$ and $V_2$, of size at most $2|V(G')|/3$ each.

Suppose that each both $|V_1\cap V(G)|$ and $|V_2\cap V(G)|$ are at least $n/r$ (where $r$ will be chosen later). In this case, the drawing of each edge of $G$ from $V_1\cap V(G)$ to $V_2\cap V(G)$ passes through $S_1$, and there are $\Omega(n/r^2)$ such edges in view of $G$ being an expander graph. Because the drawing of each such path passes through $S_1$, and no vertex of $S_1$ has degree more than $4$, it follows that $n/r^2\leq O(\sqrt{tn})$, i.e., $n=O(r^4 t)$.

This leaves the case when one of $|V_1\cap V(G)|$ or $|V_2\cap V(G)|$ is smaller than $n/r$. Say, $|V_1\cap V(G)|\leq n/100$. Then $|V_2\cap V(G)\geq (1-2/r)n$. We can then apply the separator theorem to the subgraph of $G'$ induced by $V_2$ to find a subset $S_2$ separating it into $V_2'$ and $V_3$. Again, if both $V_2'$ and $V_3$ contain $n/r$ vertices of $G$, then we find $\Omega(n)$ edges of $G$ whose drawing goes through $S_1\cup S_2$. Hence, we may assume that one of the parts, say $V_2'$, satisfies $|V_2\cap V(G)|\leq n/r$. We then repeat the argument on $V_3$, etc.

In the nested sequence $V(G')\supset V_2\supset V_3\supset\dotsb$, each next set is $\tfrac{2}{3}$ of the size of the preceding. So, $|V_{\ell}|=O\bigl( (\tfrac{2}{3})^\ell tn\bigr)$ which contradicts $|V_{\ell}\cap V(G)|\geq (1-2\ell/r)n$ if $\ell=r/4$ and $r=20\log t$. So, at some step we must have $\Omega(n/r^2)\leq |S_1|+\dotsb+|S_i|\leq O(i\sqrt{tn})$, i.e., $n=O(r^6 t)=O\bigl(t(\log t)^6\bigr)$.

The power of $\log t$ is likely improvable with more careful choice of parameters, and more careful choice of separators.

Comment: Does this show that *every* sufficiently large $3$-regular graph is not $t$-planar? The word "random" suggests "asymptotically almost every" instead.

Comment: @MattF. Of course not, a disjoint union of $4$-cliques is planar.

Comment: @MattF. $G$ is a random $3$-regular graph, and the proof shows that it works with high probability. The only step of the proof that uses randomness is the expansion property, so the proof in fact works for every $3$-regular expander (with an appropriate condition on the expansion constant in terms of $n$, which can be worked out from the proof).

Comment: That helps, it wasn’t obvious before. It might also help to add a couple words to the proof on this.

Answer (score 5):

The following is overkill compared to Boris Bukh’s answer, but it will give you a more deterministic example.

It has been proved by [Bonamy et al.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjl3cbpxrb9AhVx_7sIHVaOAn8QFnoECBUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F2012.02435&usg=AOvVaw2Wd1e4ZHx07RIAWcb0Cn39) that 1-planar (even more, (g,k)-planar for any genus $g$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$) graphs have [asymptotic dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_dimension) at most 2 (Corollary 1.6). On the other hand, we know plenty of 3-regular graphs with asymptotic dimension >2. For a concrete example, take the cubic lattice $\mathbb{Z^3}$. It is 6-regular, but you can blow up each vertex into a sub-cubic tree to make it 3-regular without affecting its asymptotic dimension, which is 3. This graph $G$ is infinite, but you can use a compactness argument to deduce that for large enough $n$, the ball of radius $n$ in $G$ is not $k$-planar.

You could try to prove this directly, by decomposing a portion of $G$ into planar `slices’, each of which is 3-connected, and therefore embeds essentially uniquely in $\mathbb{S}^2$. Thus each slice will intersect a lot with other slices.

Answer (score 4):

Did you check the [Coxeter graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_graph)?

[image]

Comment: ??@JosephO'Rourke, did you??

Comment: @WlodAA: I was unable to embed it $1$-planar.

Comment: Is there easy-to-use software for playing with the positions of the vertices and edges?

Comment: @MattF. yEd may be good. The program for testing 1-planarity can be found on GitHub (https://github.com/seemanne/1PlanarTester), but it runs relatively slow and may not meet the requirements for this graph (with 28 vertices).

Comment: @MattF. I sometimes use https://graphonline.ru/en/ to quickly play around with graphs.